# How to set check box value within container in extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to set checkbox value to false. But I am getting error on setting value.
bellow is my code for checkbox as..

```
 this.checkCombobox = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
        layout: 'hbox',
        width: '3%',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            margin: '22 10 0 0',
            boxLabel: 'All',
            //width: '10%',
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                change: function (cmp, newVal, oldVal) {
                    var combo = this.DriverNameCombo;
                    var records = combo.getStore().getRange();
                    if (newVal) {
                        combo.setValue(records, true);
                    }
                    else {
                        combo.reset();
                        combo.setValue([], false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    });
```

I want to unchecked the check box on another components event.
means I want to uncheck that check box on combobox's select event.
bello is my code for combobox.

```
     this.companyCombo = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
            xtype: 'combobox',
            width: '10%',
            fieldLabel: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_REPORTS_COMPANY_'),
            blankText: fleet.Language.get('_FLEET_REQUIRED_ERROR_'),
            labelAlign: 'top',
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'companyId',
            allowBlank: false,
            editable: true,
            store: Ext.getStore('userStore').first().companies(),
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                select: function (t, recs) {
//here I want to uncheck that checkbox if it is cheched.
                    //this.checkCombobox.items.setValue(false);
                    this.DriverNameCombo.reset();
                    recs[0].loadCompany({
                        scope: this,
                        callBack: function () {
                            this.DriverNameCombo.bindStore(recs[0].drivers());
                        }
                    });
                }
});
```

[image]

look in above image, If I select another item from Company Dropdown then I want to unchecked that all check button

Comment: Can you please share your code on fiddle.i will fix there itself

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using exactly? There are dozens of different bugs and subtle differences around checkboxes in different versions of ExtJS.

Comment: @ Alexander 
Ext JS 4.2.

Comment: @ Tejas1991. Sorry I cant able share code on fiddle

Comment: Dont get confuse. Its a simple question, there is a container having a item checkbox.. Ok..!
I want to set value to that item on another field(companyCombo in code) event (select).